# How can I assign the output of a mongosh command to a bash variable

Tags: bash, mongo-shell

I want to assign the output of a mongo command (i.e database names) to a bash array variable but I am not sure how to go about it.

I am getting an error :

```
dump.sh
Starting-BACKUP
dump.sh
./dump.sh: line 16: declare: `–a': not a valid identifier
./dump.sh: line 24: mongo: command not found   
Database backup was successful
```

when I attempt using dump.sh below:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare –a databases=()
    databases=$(mongo --quiet --uri="mongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/admin" --authenticationDatabase admin --eval="show dbs;" |  cut -d " " --field 1)
    echo $databases
```

Ordinarily I am able to get a listing of the databases when I kubectl into the pod with following steps :

```
$ kubectl exec -it mongodb-prom-xxxxxxxxx-dddx4 -- sh
$ mongo
> use admin
> db.auth('root','mypassword')
> show dbs
admin      0.000GB
platforms  0.000GB
users      0.000GB
```

I am not sure why the mongo command is not being recognized because the **same script** *is able to execute the mongodump command below*  :

```
mongodump --uri="<uri_here>" --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --archive=/tmp/"<variable_here>".gz
```

**UPDATE** : This is the associated Dockerfile. My expectation is that both mongo and mongodump should be working by default in a mongo container but it seems only mongodump is working for now

```
FROM mongo
WORKDIR /opt/backup/
WORKDIR /usr/src/configs
COPY dump.sh .
RUN chmod +x dump.sh
```

My two issues :

1. Is my syntax correct for the variable assignment (I suspect its not correct) ?
2. How should I properly declare the array variable to avoid the warnings ?

NB : Mongo tooling is already installed on the container and is actually working for mongodump

Comment: `declare -a` is a `bash` command. You don't have `#!/bin/bash` in your script.

Comment: @Barmar shebang is already in the script.. my bad had left it out. Script updated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `declare -a`. Simply putting the value inside `()` in the assignment will make it an array.

To get all the elements of an array, you have to use `${variable[@]}`. `$variable` is equivalent to `${variable[0]}` and just retrieves the first element.

```
databases=($(mongo --quiet --uri="mongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/admin" --authenticationDatabase admin --eval="show dbs;" |  cut -d " " --field 1))
echo "${databases[@]}"
```

Comment: I have amended but Im still getting same error : ./dump.sh: line 25: mongo: command not found

Comment: Added the Dockerfile for context but mongo should really be working because its a mongo container by definition

Comment: That's a problem with your `$PATH`, it doesn't include the directory containing the `mongo` command.

Comment: I don't know anything about Docker, just shell scripting.

Comment: strange though because mongodump is working perfectly. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

With bashv4+, `mapfile` is available, with [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
mapfile -t databases < <(mongo --quiet --uri="mongodb://root:mypassword@mongodb-prom/admin" --authenticationDatabase admin --eval="show dbs;" |  cut -d " " --field 1)
```

Now check the value of the databases array

```
declare -p databases
```

---

Your code has

```
declare -a databases=()
```

but

```
databases=$(...)
```

is not an array, the `$(...)` construct is [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

---

See also [Bash Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)